# Undefined references despite linking properly

Tags: c, linker, sdl-2

I am trying to compile the following test program:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("test", 0, 0, 640, 480, 0);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
}
```

I am compiling first on the command line and I am using the following command (I will add warning options later):

```
gcc test.c -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

Upon compiling this program I receive the following undefined reference errors:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\JACOBD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cceuyYlI.o:test.c:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\JACOBD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cceuyYlI.o:test.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As seen in the above errors I am currently using gcc 9.2.0 from http://www.mingw.org/. On my other development machine I use TDM-GCC version 5.1.0 from https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/ on which this test program among other SDL2 programs do compile properly.

I checked the libraries that I was linking against with nm and found the following which was a bit worrying:

```
nm: effect_position.o: file format not recognized
nm: effect_stereoreverse.o: file format not recognized
nm: effects_internal.o: file format not recognized
nm: load_aiff.o: file format not recognized
nm: load_voc.o: file format not recognized
...
nm: native_midi_win32.o: file format not recognized
```

I am unclear what the issue is. From what I can see I have placed all libraries and includes in the proper location.

Comment: You probably have the wrong libraries. Either those are 32-bit and you're using a 64-bit compiler, or vice versa.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's what I was thinking. It seems that you can compile in 32-bit mode only in TDM-GCC whereas with this new compiler it is 64-bit mode.

Comment: So, does it work if you use 64-bit libraries?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It looks like the precompiled binary of gcc doesn't have 64-bit mode available. I switched over to the 32 bit libraries and it worked. Gonna try and get 64 bit mode in there.

Comment: You could try installing GCC from MSYS2. It has the latest GCC version (10.0.2) for both 32 and 64 bits, and some other nice features.